# How to overwrite a symbolic link of a directory?

Tags: linux, macos, ln

There are two directories `foo1` and `foo2`.

At first I make a directory symlink by `ln -s foo1 bar`.
After that I want to change the symlink, so I typed `ln -sf foo2 bar`

But `bar` is still linked with `foo1`.
Symlink `foo2` is created inside of `foo1`.

What should I type when I want to replace `foo1` by `foo2`?

I tested in three environments.

1. Ubuntu 12.04, ln (GNU coreutils) 8.13
2. CentOS 6.4, ln (GNU coreutils) 8.4
3. OS X 10.7.5, ln (without version)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to use the `-n, --no-dereference` option like so.

```
$ ln -snf foo2 bar
```

This causes `ln` to treat the existing symlink as a file. Otherwise, it dereferences `bar` to `foo1`, descends into `foo1` and uses the original `TARGET` name as the `LINK_NAME` and that's why you end up with a symlink to `foo2` being created inside the `foo1` directory. The manpage on `ln` states the following...

```
-n, --no-dereference
       treat  LINK_NAME  as a normal file if it is a symbolic link to a
       directory
```

Below is the shell output on my Arch Linux desktop with version 8.21 of `ln` with and without the `--no-dereference` option, I got the same results you did without the `--no-dereference` option, but using the `--no-dereference` option it worked as expected.

```
$ mkdir foo1 foo2
$ ln -s foo1 bar
$ ls -l bar
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 drew users 4 Sep 17 12:51 bar -> foo1
$ ln -sf foo2 bar
$ ls -l bar
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 drew users 4 Sep 17 12:51 bar -> foo1
$ ls -l foo1
  total 0
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 drew users 4 Sep 17 12:51 foo2 -> foo2
$ ln -snf foo2 bar
$ ls -l bar
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 drew users 4 Sep 17 12:52 bar -> foo2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If it is environment dependent problem, I will write my environment. Which os are you using? what outputs `ln --version`?

Comment: I tried this on a Fedora 18 VM with version 8.17. Interestingly, I tried this on my Arch Linux desktop with version 8.21 and got the same results you did. Looks like somewhere inbetween those two versions something changed. The solution I posted worked in both instances though.

Comment: FYI, I found this answer on the [justlinux.com forums](http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?117847-why-doesn-t-ln-sf-work).

Comment: Thanks druciferre! I even never thought that the `ln` command so often upgrade.

Comment: I tested in osx also. `ln` works same as ubuntu and centos with the directory overwrite and `ln -snf` solve the problem. Even though `ln -h` is prefer option to use in osx.

Comment: @Tetsu, I also confirmed it on FreeBSD.

Comment: Great, this is even working with busybox; many thanks!